# ayuda con consulta sql para reporte

Tags: sql

tengo que elaborar un reporte en crystal report, que muestre los campos de clave,de cliente,nombre de cliente,monto del credito y la fecha del prestamo. al momento de ejecutar lo que ya tengo me tira un error en el "fill de datos" asumo que la consulta esta mal, espero me puedan ayudar ya que no soy mucho de programar o cosas asi

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("server=DESKTOP-SAHPQ10;Database=SistemadeVentas;UID=sa;Pwd=avilalopez12;")
        Dim comando As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("Select Clientes.id_cliente,nombrecliente,apellido_paterno,apellido_materno,fecha_credito,monto,pagado from Clientes", con)
        Dim adaptador As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter
        con.Open()
        datos.Clear()
        adaptador.SelectCommand = comando
        adaptador.Fill(datos, "creditos")
        Dim rpt As New CrystalReport1
        rpt.Load()
        rpt.SetDataSource(datos)
        rpt.Refresh()
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt
        rpt.Refresh()
```

Comment: Que haces con "datos.clear()"?

Comment: que error te muestra ?

Comment: ¿En qué lenguaje estás trabajando?

Comment: Al parecer es Visual Basic, muestra mas de tu código, no sabemos que es datos.Clear() (esá limpiando, pero que cosa?)

Comment: Parece que tu sentencia SQL está mal estructurada, prueba dicho Query en tu IDE de BD y asegúrate de que funcione.

Answer (score 0):

Corrige tu Query SQL:

```
Dim comando As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT X.id_cliente, X.apellido_paterno, X.apellido_materno, X.fecha_credito, X.monto, X.pagado FROM Clientes X", con);
```

---

**Recomendación :** Cuando realices una pregunta te sugiero que las credenciales de tu conexión no la expongas, esto debe ser privado :

```
Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("server=*****Database=********;UID=**;Pwd=*********;")
```